# ASP.NET Listbox Height

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listbox

So I have a `<div>` and inside that i have a `<p>` with `<asp:ListBox>` and I am trying to make this list box so that it can display at least 10 items at a time. I have tried `Rows="10"` or `Size="10"` and also `Height"100%".

It might be worthing adding that it is in a popup rather than a page itself (the size may be restricted to the size of the popup window maybe) but you can see this in the following code:

```
<div  class="left_panel my">
    <div class="form_fieldTxtarea_Dv">
        <label>Hospital<span class="man">*</span></label>
        <p>
            <asp:ListBox 
                ID="lstHospital" 
                runat="server" 
                Height="100%" 
                ToolTip="Select Hospital" 
                class="form-control 
                textAreah" TabIndex="1"
                SelectionMode="Multiple">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </p>
        <p class="error_msg">
            <asp:Label ID="lblHospitalError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate all your helpful inputs.  **Just let me know if I should post an image of what it looks like currently**. It shows 3 and a bit default.

Answer (score 2):

`Rows="10"` should work. You can use CSS to style it too...

```css
#lstHospital { height: 200px;}
```

Be sure it fits within the popup (define the min height for pop-up itself).

Comment: Is it possible to set the size within the `<asp:ListBox>` tag?

Comment: I don't think so. Can't you use css script? You can place it inline, just above or below the ListBox tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Rows="10" into the ListBox

```
 <asp:ListBox> 
        ID="lstHospital"
        Rows="10" 
        ....
        SelectionMode="Multiple">
    </asp:ListBox>
```